# Get Contacts folder items using ews in office 365

Tags: soap, office365, exchangewebservices, outlook-web-app

I'm using the following SOAP request to retrieve the items in contacts folder in office 365 mail addin

```
'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>'+
    ' <soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"' +
     ' xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"' +
            ' xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types"'+
            ' xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages">'+
    ' <soap:Header>'+
       ' <t:RequestServerVersion Version="Exchange2013" />' +
    ' </soap:Header>'+
    ' <soap:Body >'+
       ' <m:FindPeople>'+
          ' <m:IndexedPageItemView BasePoint="Beginning" MaxEntriesReturned="100" Offset="0"/>'+
          ' <m:ParentFolderId>'+
             ' <t:DistinguishedFolderId Id="contacts"/>'+
          ' </m:ParentFolderId>'+
      ' </m:FindPeople>'+
    ' </soap:Body>'+
    ' </soap:Envelope>';
```

But the following error shows up.

[image: error]

I have used FindItem , GetFolder methods for calendar folder and those are working.

Is there anyway to look for people email address by using the name as search value.

Answer (score 1):

the  makeEwsRequestAsync in Mail Apps only supports a subset of EWS operations which FindPeople is not one of. You can see a full list of supported operations on https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp160952.aspx .

> > Is there anyway to look for people email address by using the name as search value.

Sure just use a FindItem with a restriction on the DisplayName eg

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:m="
http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages" xmlns:t="http://sc
hemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xml
soap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Header>
    <t:RequestServerVersion Version="Exchange2013_SP1" />
  </soap:Header>
  <soap:Body>
    <m:FindItem Traversal="Shallow">
      <m:ItemShape>
        <t:BaseShape>AllProperties</t:BaseShape>
      </m:ItemShape>
      <m:IndexedPageItemView MaxEntriesReturned="1000" Offset="0" BasePoint="Beginning" />
      <m:Restriction>
        <t:Contains ContainmentMode="Substring" ContainmentComparison="IgnoreCase">
          <t:FieldURI FieldURI="contacts:DisplayName" />
          <t:Constant Value="Blah blah" />
        </t:Contains>
      </m:Restriction>
      <m:ParentFolderIds>
        <t:DistinguishedFolderId Id="contacts" />
      </m:ParentFolderIds>
    </m:FindItem>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Cheers
Glen

Comment: The response is always empty. i tried with exact names as in my contacts folder. :(

Comment: What if you make the same query without the restriction in that case you should just get all the Contact Items in the Contacts folder if you don't your not querying the correct folder

Comment: yes. without restriction, the response is still empty. But the people data will reside in contacts folder, right?

Comment: also, on which scenario we can use FindPeople ? I mean if it is restricted in MailApps , how can i use the FindPeople  method.

Comment: In MailApps you can't use FindPeople

Comment: What do you mean by people data sounds like you mixing up query the Global Address List ?? querying the Contacts folder will return the Contacts in a Mailbox you should get something unless there are no contacts in the Mailbox at all. I would suggest you do a little testing of EWS using the EWSEditor and work out what you actually want to do and understand the results you will get returned